# Is it possible do serialize/deserialize multilevel json objects?

Tags: java, jackson

When I have a simple json it is easy, take

```
{"type":"simple","content":"i love apples"}
```

I just create a pojo:

```
public class Example {
    public Object type;
    public Object content;
}
```

Then doing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Example ex = mapper.readValue(getInputStream(),Example.class)
```

will do the job.

But now suppose I have something more complicated, a multilevel json

```
{
    "type": "complicated",
    "params": [
        {
            "type": "simple",
            "content": "i still love apples"
        },
        {
            "type": "simple", 
            "content":"i love spam too"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the "params" field of this new Object is a json array, and each element of this array could be mapped to my `Example` pojo class.

Is there a way to do this? Sorry if it could seem trivial, but I can't find any good documentation about jackson... it just talks about simple cases.

Comment: It is perfectly possible; Jackson is able to deserialize collections easily

Comment: Could you please point me to a tutorial or reference of this?

Comment: See my answer. Note: Jackson 2.0.x or upper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

NOTE: no setters in the class, which is why I have to use `@JsonCreator`. Habit of mine, I don't do beans ;)

If you have setters for the different fields you can do without `@JsonCreator` at all.

```
public final class Jackson
{
    private static final String JSONCONTENT
        = "{" +
            "\"type\":\"complicated\"," +
            "\"params\":[" +
            "{\"type\":\"simple\"," + "\"content\":\"i still love apples\"}," +
            "{\"type\":\"simple\",\"content\":\"i love spam too\"}" +
            "]" +
        "}";
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final Complicated complicated
            = mapper.readValue(JSONCONTENT, Complicated.class);
        System.out.println("Deserialization done");
        System.out.println("Serializing");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(complicated));
    }
}

class Complicated
{
    private final String type;
    private final List<Simple> params;

    @JsonCreator
    Complicated(@JsonProperty("type") final String type,
        @JsonProperty("params") final List<Simple> params)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.params = new ArrayList<Simple>(params);
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public List<Simple> getParams()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(params);
    }
}

class Simple
{
    private final String type;
    private final String content;

    @JsonCreator
    Simple(@JsonProperty("type") final String type,
        @JsonProperty("content") final String content)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public String getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, just a question: are those annotation really needed? It seems working even without them...

Comment: Oh well np, ty for your help this example was all I needed to get started ;)

Comment: Well, anyway -- this is only scratching the surface of what Jackson can do. It can do MUCH more than that...

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can use google gson : https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Using that library the following simple code produces the output you want :

```
@Test
public void testGson() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Param param = new Param("simple", "i still love apples");
    Enclosure enclosure = new Enclosure("complex", param);
    String json = gson.toJson(enclosure);
    System.out.println(json);
}
output : {"type":"complex","param":{"type":"simple","content":"i still love apples"}}
```

You can also do more complex serializations using Gson so it should fit your needs as you expand in serialization.

Comment: Why? You can do that with Jackson as well

Comment: Interesting. The OP doesn't specify that he wants the answer to be in Jackson. So I assumed that he had already tried Jackson and was then looking for a simple way to do what he wanted. Sorry, I am not familiar with Jackson to tell one way or the other. However if you assert Jackson can do it, no problem.

Comment: so what? look at the specific comments - it says "Is there a way to do this?". The title has no mention of Jackson : Is it possible do serialize/deserialize multilevel json objects? At the very least my answer provides the OP an alternative to investigate.

Comment: I am in the phase of choosing the best library for my task. I have looked at jackson because it seems to be the most performant, but if there is another library which allows me to do the same in an easy way it is welcome.

Comment: Its worth it to consider google gson if you are mainly interested in going from Java objects to Json and vice versa. From the google gson webpage : "There are a few open-source projects that can convert Java objects to JSON. However, most of them require that you place Java annotations in your classes; something that you can not do if you do not have access to the source-code. Most also do not fully support the use of Java Generics. Gson considers both of these as very important design goals."

Comment: Jackson can do both of that too; my example above uses annotations only because my classes have no setters; if you have setters you don't even need `@JsonCreator`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, I don't know how it is with Jackson but in many JSON libraries it works when you have a List of Objects in your Example class.

Answer (score -1):

it's possible. Here is an example with flexjson:

1. I have a list of groups, in that every groups has a list of users
2. The relevant code sequence:

   ```
   try (
           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( outputFileName ); )
   {
       oos.writeObject( groupList );
       fos.write( baos.toByteArray() );
   }
   ```